# Is there an easy way to horizontally center Bootstrap navbar elements on the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a CSS beginner and I want to center Bootstrap navbar horizontally on the page (that is, the navbar itself extends over the width of the page, but the elements in it should be center-aligned with respect to the navbar). How can I do this?
My HTML code is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Test page</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" 
      crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs- 
             target="#navbarSupportedContent"
             aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle 
             navigation">
                 <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" 
                         role="button"
                         data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li>
                               <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                            </li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria- 
                       disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria- 
                    label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
               </form>
          </div>
     </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Whereas in my CSS file styles.css I try to center the navbar (but it remains fixed in the initial position):

```
.navbar {
     text-align: center;
}
```

How can I solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center your navbar content, as `justify-content-lg-center` to your container to use flex to center everything, and add `flex-lg-grow-0` to your navbar-collapse div so that it doesn’t grow (normally, that div grows to take up the available space, pushing the search form to the right).

Some of your attributes had a space in them like `data-bs- target` which won’t work correctly. Running your code through the [W3 Validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) one in a while is a good way to be sure there aren’t any typos.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid justify-content-lg-center">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle 
            navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-lg-grow-0 id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex">
                <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I used Stackoverflow's snippet tool as it's a handy way to see the code in operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! I'm sorry for the code formatting but this is my first question on StackOverflow. I'll learn how to use the snippet tool.